# Dangling Pointer- please verify

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, binary-search-tree, dangling-pointer

Could someone verify and tell me if the following code is valid ? I feel lines 160-162 might be wrong. 
 I have comments to indicate the line number.

 the full code is taken from here [C++ Binary Search tree](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/1551/)

```
class BinarySearchTree
{
    private:
        struct tree_node
        {
           tree_node* left;
           tree_node* right;
           int data;
        };
        tree_node* root;

    public:
        BinarySearchTree()
        {
           root = NULL;
        }

        bool isEmpty() const { return root==NULL; }
        void print_inorder();
        void inorder(tree_node*);
        void print_preorder();
        void preorder(tree_node*);
        void print_postorder();
        void postorder(tree_node*);
        void insert(int);
        void remove(int);
};


void BinarySearchTree::remove(int d)
{
    //Locate the element
    bool found = false;
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        cout<<" This Tree is empty! "<<endl;
        return;
    }

    tree_node* curr;
    tree_node* parent;
    curr = root;

    while(curr != NULL)
    {
         if(curr->data == d)
         {
            found = true;
            break;
         }
         else
         {
             parent = curr;
             if(d>curr->data) curr = curr->right;
             else curr = curr->left;
         }
    }
    if(!found)
         {
        cout<<" Data not found! "<<endl;
        return;
    }


         // 3 cases :
    // 1. We're removing a leaf node
    // 2. We're removing a node with a single child
    // 3. we're removing a node with 2 children

    // Node with single child
    if((curr->left == NULL && curr->right != NULL)|| (curr->left != NULL
&& curr->right == NULL))
    {
       if(curr->left == NULL && curr->right != NULL)
       {
           if(parent->left == curr)
           {
             parent->left = curr->right;
             delete curr;
           }
           else
           {
             parent->right = curr->right;
             delete curr;
           }
       }
       else // left child present, no right child
       {
          if(parent->left == curr)
           {
             parent->left = curr->left;
             delete curr;
           }
           else
           {
             parent->right = curr->left;
             delete curr;
           }
       }
     return;
    }

         //We're looking at a leaf node
         if( curr->left == NULL && curr->right == NULL)
    {
        if(parent->left == curr) parent->left = NULL;
        else parent->right = NULL;
                 delete curr;
                 return;
    }


    //Node with 2 children
    // replace node with smallest value in right subtree
    if (curr->left != NULL && curr->right != NULL)
    {
        tree_node* chkr;
        chkr = curr->right;
        if((chkr->left == NULL) && (chkr->right == NULL))
        {
            curr = chkr;  // <----------- line 160
            delete chkr;
            curr->right = NULL; // <------------------ line 162
        }
        else // right child has children
        {
            //if the node's right child has a left child
            // Move all the way down left to locate smallest element

            if((curr->right)->left != NULL)
            {
                tree_node* lcurr;
                tree_node* lcurrp;
                lcurrp = curr->right;
                lcurr = (curr->right)->left;
                while(lcurr->left != NULL)
                {
                   lcurrp = lcurr;
                   lcurr = lcurr->left;
                }
        curr->data = lcurr->data;
                delete lcurr;
                lcurrp->left = NULL;
           }
           else
           {
               tree_node* tmp;
               tmp = curr->right;
               curr->data = tmp->data;
           curr->right = tmp->right;
               delete tmp;
           }

        }
         return;
    }

}
```

*curr* and *chkr* point to the same location. By deleting *chkr* can the same location still be accessed by *curr* ? Or is this alright because neither of them were actually allocated any memory using the new statement.

There is something really dodgy about the code. I feel that there is a memory leak too. I am a working professional looking to refresh on my C++ basics. Thank you for any help.

Comment: I would copy the part of the code that you are talking about here along with the class definition.

Comment: "Really dodgy" is right - that code has all kinds of issues. You may want to refresh your knowledge elsewhere :-)

Comment: Could someone suggest the correct way to code the part I mentioned ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave a glance at the code around the region you mentioned. I believe you are correct as this is a bug.

```
void BinarySearchTree::remove(int d)
{

...

    tree_node* curr;
    tree_node* parent;
    curr = root;

...    

    //Node with 2 children
    // replace node with smallest value in right subtree
    if (curr->left != NULL && curr->right != NULL)
    {
        tree_node* chkr;
        chkr = curr->right;
        if((chkr->left == NULL) && (chkr->right == NULL))
        {
            curr = chkr;
            delete chkr;
            curr->right = NULL;
        }
```

In this code section, curr and chkr are both declared as a pointer to a tree_node instance. While running `curr = chkr`, pointer value for chkr is wirtten to curr and thus point curr to instance chkr is pointing to. By `delete chkr`, the instance is destroyed and garbage collected. Thus curr is now pointing to a non-existed object who is out of life. This IS a dangling pointer by definition, if I remember correctly.

If I'm all correct above and the understanding for that particular chunk, the following is the fix for this:

```
curr->data = chkr->data;
```

to replace

```
       curr = chkr;
```

Regarding memory leak. Sorry, I did not read the whole code. It appears msram's code should be merely for displaying the correct logic. That is a lot more extra information for that purpose though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, lines 160-162 contain an error as you have described.  He is writing to memory that he has released with `delete`.